# Are the following groups isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I have to find out if these groups are isomorphic:

1. $( { \mathbb {Q} };+) $ and $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z};+)$ - (this exercise is the most important for me)
2. $( { \mathbb {Q} };+)$ and $( { \mathbb {Q} \times \mathbb {Q} };+)$
3. $(ℝ;+)$and $(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R};+)$

I have tried to solve 1. and first of all I have tried to find some property which could show that these two groups can not be  isomorphic. But I have not find such property so I think that $( { \mathbb {Q} };+) $ and $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z};+)$ are isomorphic, but I can not to prove it, I can not find some isomorphism.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is divisible.

Comment: Try to think about the difference between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ as sets.

Comment: If $x\in\Bbb Q$ there is $y\in\Bbb Q$ with $x=y+y$.

Comment: @Alex How would thinking just of the sets help?

Comment: Is "$+$" in $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z};+)$ defined as $(p_1,q_1)+(p_2,q_2)=(p_1q_2+p_2q_1,p_1q_2)$ (i.e. like normal fractions) ?

Comment: One approach for (1) is to note that $(\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z,+)$ is finitely generated whereas $(\Bbb Q,+)$ is not.

Comment: @user505973, no, it's component-wise addition. It's a subgroup of $(\Bbb R^2,+)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Every homomorphism from $\mathbb Q$ to $C_2$ is trivial. Indeed, let $x \in \mathbb Q$. Write $x=2y$. If $y \mapsto g$, then $x \mapsto g^2 = e$. On the other hand, there is a nontrivial homomorphism from $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ to $C_2$ given by $(m,n) \mapsto g^m$.
   A simpler reason is that every element in $\mathbb Q$ is a square, that is, $x \mapsto 2x$ is surjective. But not every element of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$  is a square, that is, of the form $(2m,2n)$.
2. Consider $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ as vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$. Every additive map $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ is actually a linear transformation. But $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ have different dimensions.
3. The argument above does *not* apply to $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ as vector spaces over $\mathbb R$ because not every additive map is a linear transformation. Nevertheless, $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ have the same dimension as vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$ and so are isomorphic.

Comment: Plus one. But I would say that #2 needs more talk. The groups $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ have one and only one structure as $\Bbb Z$-modules. As they are uniquely divisible, each has one and only one structure as $\Bbb Q$-module. Then I would continue as you do.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a free-abelian group, see here:

[How can we show that $\mathbb Q$ is not free?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129337/how-can-we-show-that-mathbb-q-is-not-free)

On the other hand $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is free of rank $2$.