# Decomposing a module into a direct sum of torsion and free part?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules, torsion-groups

I know by the  fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups that we can write any $\mathbb{Z}$-module of the form

$$A\cong \mathbb{Z}^r\oplus Tor(A) $$

Can we not also decompose any general $\mathbb{Z}$-module to such a form of

$$ A\cong F(A)\oplus Tor(A) $$

where $F(A)$ is the free part of $A$? If not, is there any generalization to the setting of **infinitely** generated $\mathbb{Z}$-modules? I was not able to find any answers on this site dealing with removing the assumption of being finitely generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were true for infinitely generated $\mathbb Z$ modules, then $\mathbb Q_\mathbb Z$ would be a free $\mathbb Z$ module, [but it is not](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/129337/29335).